# Как проверить на JS при submit формы, что страница загружается?

Tags: javascript

Каким образом можно проверить, что страница в процессе загрузки после нажатия на кнопку? В моём случае `document.readyState` всегда выдаёт complete. Нужно именно проверить на JS, что страница в процессе загрузки, а не назначать кнопке что-либо.

```
<?php
$act = (isset($_REQUEST['act']) ? $_REQUEST['act'] : '');

if($act == 'test') {
 sleep(20);
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="/?act=test">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(document.readyState);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Ну, document это html, по большому счету, он тут ничего не покажет. Можно на форму повесить самбит и при старте ставить флаг что он начался

Comment: @InDevX, тоже хорошая идея кстати. Жду ещё варианты. Пока оформите как ответ, пожалуйста, чтобы я смог его в дальнейшем выбрать правильным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно добавить событие на отправку формы и с его помощью записывать когда началась загрузка.

```
var submitStarted = false;
document.getElementById('myFormId').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    submitStarted = true;
});
```